# Displaying images in recyclerview retrieved from retrofit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm new in android development and building a movie app in which I'm using recyclerview to display movie images and using retrofit to fetch data from themoviedb.org API.

I'm successfully getting the data from the mention URL but not able to display it on the screen.

GenreModel class:

```
data class Genre (
    var genres: ArrayList<GenreList>
): Serializable

data class GenreList (
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val results: ArrayList<Results>
): Serializable

data class Results (
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var poster_path: String,
    var release_date: String,
    var original_language: String,
    var overview: String
): Serializable
```

Function to get movie details from API:

```
private fun getGenreName() {
        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
        val apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val genreListCall: Call<Genre> = apiInterface.getGenreDetails(Constants.APP_ID)
        genreListCall.enqueue(object: Callback<Genre> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Genre>, response: Response<Genre>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful) {
                    val result: Genre? = response.body() // returns genres object which contains ID and Name
                    val genres: ArrayList<GenreList> = result!!.genres// saves ID and Names of genres
                    for(x in genres) {
                        val id = x.id
                        val name = x.name // returns the genre names. Ex- action, family, drama....
                        val listCall: Call<GenreList> = apiInterface.getGenreMovieDetails(id, Constants.APP_ID)
                        listCall.enqueue(object: Callback<GenreList> {
                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<GenreList>, response: Response<GenreList>) {
                                if(response.isSuccessful) {   // returns id, results[]
                                    val result1: GenreList? = response.body()
                                    results = result1!!.results  // results[id, title, poster, language....]
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<GenreList>, t: Throwable) {
                                Log.e("ERRORInGenreMovieList", t.message.toString())
                            }

                        })
                        genreList.add(GenreList(id, name, results))
                        genreCategories.add(name)
                    }
                } else {
                    val rc = response.code()
                    when (rc) {
                        400 -> {
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Connection")
                        }
                        404 -> {
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found")
                        }
                        else -> {
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Genre>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("ERROR in Genre Name", t.message.toString())
            }
        })
    }
```

GenreAdapter for recyclerview:

```
class GenreFragmentAdapter(private val genreList: ArrayList<GenreList>, val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<GenreFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var genreName:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.genreName)
        var genreListRecyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.genreListRecyclerView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.genre_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val name = genreList[position].name
        val results = genreList[position].results
        holder.genreName.text = name
        println("Name: $name")
        setItemRecyclerView(holder.genreListRecyclerView, results)
        println("Results: $results")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return genreList.size
    }

    private fun setItemRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, results: ArrayList<Results>) {
        val genreListAdapter = GenreResultsAdapter(results, context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = genreListAdapter
    }
}
```

**BaseUrl: https://api.themoviedb.org**

ApiInterface:

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/3/genre/movie/list") // returns genre list
    fun getGenreDetails(
        @Query("api_key") api_key: String
    ): Call<Genre>

    @GET("/3/genre/{id}/movies") // returns movie details according to specified genre
    fun getGenreMovieDetails(
        @Path("id") id: Int,
        @Query("api_key") api_key: String
    ): Call<GenreList>

    @GET("/3/movie/upcoming") // returns upcoming movies
    fun getUpcomingMovies(
        @Query("api_key") api_key: String
    ): Call<GenreList>

    @GET("/3/movie/{id}")
    fun getMovie(
        @Path("id") id: Int,
        @Query("api_key") api_key: String
    ): Call<Results>
}
```

RetrofitClient:

```
object RetrofitClient {

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient()!!.build())
            .build()
    }

    private fun getUnsafeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient.Builder? {
        return try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(
                object : X509TrustManager {
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?, authType: String?) {
                    }

                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?, authType: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate?>? {
                        return arrayOf()
                    }
                }
            )

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())

            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
            val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
            builder.hostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }
            builder
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post here your image path!

Comment: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500: this is the base url for image

Comment: data is not showing or only the image does not load!

Comment: image does not load. data is showing in console

Comment: Which library are you using for image load!

Comment: I'm using Glide library